# Cannabis laws in Northern Cyprus

Tags: criminal-law, drugs

How strict are Cannabis laws in North Cyprus, i.e. if you caught with 150 grams of Cannabis? What would the punishment be, and is it usually easy to get bail with that sort of crime?

Comment: 150 grams of cannabis is about 5.3 ounces, which would _probably_ fall under "Personal Consumption" amounts. I have no idea about North Cyprus laws, but, 5.3 ounces definitely isn't "intent to distribute" in any book.